# Mule Requester returns a org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector when opening files

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-esb

I am using the Mule Requester 1.5 in Anypoint 6.4.4 and am trying to open jpg and text files using the requester. However, the requester returns a payload of org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$7@76186b59 which doesn't actually contain the file contents. I tried to convert the result to a byte array using an object to byte array transformer but it didn't work. I also tried the byte array to string transformers but nothing works.

As an example, I used the requester to open a simple text file and when the returned object converted to a string, it was not readable text. Similarly, if I used the requester to open a jpg and write the results back to a file, the new file is corrupted and cannot be opened.

Below is a snippet of the flow with which I am having the problem.

```html
                <when expression="#[payload.PHOTO1 != null]">                                       
                   <mulerequester:request resource="file:///tmp/flowlogs/complaints/photos/PL.0705-photo1.jpg" doc:name="Retrieve Image" timeout="10000"/>
                   <!--<object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/> -->
                    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>

                    <expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[flowVars['PHOTO1']=message.payloadAs(java.lang.String);]]></expression-component>
                    <logger level="ERROR" doc:name="Logger" message="Photo Data from file is :#[payload]"/>
                </when>
```

I have added specific connector references to the requester but I still get the same result. The object is returned with the correct file size and location, suggesting that the requester has found the file.

Am I missing something here? I thought the requester would just return the file contents as the payload. Where can I find the actual file contents or is there something else I need to do?

Thanks.